# Any ways to run program debugging in Visual Studio on NVIDIA graphics card?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, opengl, visual-studio-2013

I have notebook with integrated Intel and NVIDIA graphic cards and I want to run my program (written in C# with .NET) debugging in Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition on NVIDIA card, as my program extensively works with OpenGL and Intel card not support latest OpenGL features. But by default settings program runs on Intel card.

I have tried changing default graphic card for my program in NVIDIA settings, but it looks like after program recompiling settings are reset.

So, are there any other simple ways to run program on NVIDIA graphics card? Maybe there are special command line parameters or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of hours of searching I found the solution at http://drivenbynostalgia.com/files/SOP.cs

I guess it's better than moving the entire project into dll and using C++/CLI launcher.

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way is to just add this piece of code somewhere in your program:

```
extern "C" {
    _declspec(dllexport) DWORD NvOptimusEnablement = 0x00000001;
}
```

For more info, take a look here : http://developer.download.nvidia.com/devzone/devcenter/gamegraphics/files/OptimusRenderingPolicies.pdf

Comment: But my program written with .NET, so I can't export variables. At least without some hacking of compiled assembly.

Comment: Another solution may be to set the default graphic card to nvidia in the nvidia control panel. But there is probably a trick to export this variable in .Net.

Answer (score 2):

I currently use Visual Studio 2017 Professional edition and I also need to use OpenGL. Like @Omich said, to change default graphic card for VS2017 in NVIDIA settings does not work. Finally I try to **right click** the "Visual Studio 2017" shortcut (or the devenv.exe, just the same result) and select the option "**Run with graphics processor->high performance NVIDIA procesor**" and it just works. This way is simple but it seems a little trivil since you have to right click your VS icon every time you start it.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is probably to compile your program into a .NET DLL and call your `Main` function from an executable written in C++/CLI that exports the `NvOptimusEnablement` variable as Jerem has mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: What about linking a DLL written in c++ that exports this variable. Would that work?

Comment: @Jerem: I thought about that, but I'm not sure if it would work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the NVidia Control Panel app. I believe it is installed when installing the NVidia driver, but I'm not exactly sure about that. Start it up and:

Select Manage 3D Settings -> Program Settings tab

1. Select program to customize: click Add button
   Locate your executable and click Add Selected Program
2. Select preferred graphics processor...
   Select your NVidia processor

When you run your exe, even using Visual Studio Debugger, it will use the selected graphics processor.

Comment: Did you test it? I know what you mean, but I know there are sometimes oddities that the parent launcher EXE will make the child EXE inherit it and then you either run the host/parent on discrete GPU all the time or the child will get run on the integrated all the time

Comment: Yes I tested it. Using Visual Studio 2019, I built a .exe. Then opened NVidia Control Panel app and browsed to the exe as per directions above. Went back to Visual Studio and ran .exe through debugger. My Windows Taskbar has an icon for NVidia, whenever it's being used it lights up, and also lists the programs using the card. The icon lights up for this new .exe. It continues to light up even after I modify and rebuild the .exe.